# Which version APK i need to upload to Play store?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 2 and below is how my gradle file looks.
My application builds without any error. Now as minSdkVersion is 15 , does that means if i publish the APK from my machine, it will run well on Android SDK version 15 also ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mfr.abc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will run on version 15.

Not really sure what you mean by `run well`. If you have tested your app against SDK version 15 and it runs fine, your published apk would run fine as well.

As to which apk version should you build your app with, on `create new project` on Android Studio, click `Help me choose`, it will show you reception for different SDKs. [image: Help me choose screen at the time of writing.]

While you are building with a minSDKVersion, if you call deprecated methods on APIs such as `AdMob`, if those methods are no longer supported, you should upgrade them, so that they don't break at lower APIs.

Comment: looking at the dependencies, Can you tell me if the Admob API will work on SDK version 15 ? I assume it should work otherwise the IDE would have thrown error. Correct me If i am wrong.

Comment: I have looked at major functions and it should work. For all the calls that you are making to `AdMob`, just make sure IDE doesn't give you any warning.

Comment: IDE doesn't throw error for versions mismatch i.e if you are making a call that is supported only by API 23, and not by 15, it would crash. IDE would definitely show you a warning, where ever you are making any such calls. Run your apk on an SDK 15 emulator, it will clear up everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

No. It does not means that it will run WELL.

But it means that users with API level 15 (or later) will be able to install your app.

Defining a minSdkVersion does not meant that your application will work well. It just tells to Google Play that your app can run in Phones with API 15 or later. But it is your responsibility to ensure that your app really support all API version from 15 onwards.

It is better to test in different Android Versions your app before releasing it.

There are lot of runtime errors that are not catch during "compilation" time.

Some errors just triggers a warning in Android studio. So, you can generate an APK with those errors.

There are also a lot of xml attributes that were added in different Android version... So, even the UI may not be rendered properly.

It's better to test before release the APK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your app will run on API version 15.

Comment: So the admob stuff my application uses, will still run on API version 15  and above ?

Comment: Yes, AdMob requires Android level 9 or higher.